# How to compute difference of two arrays of different lengths?

Tags: python, arrays

[image]

I am running a code in a simulator and on a real robot. Due to differences in the sampling times, I get two arrays of different lengths measuring the position and the time of that recorded position. What I want to do now is to compare them to then compute the error between the two.

The lists consist of different values for time and different values for x-position. What I have done is scale the time values lists. By doing this I get very similar plots for both.
I wanted to simply compute the difference between the x-positions, but this is not possible, since the simulator list is of length 580 and the robot list is of length 300.
The way I scaled the Times lists is as follows:

```py
self.T_odom = [i / self.T_odom[-1] for i in self.T_odom]
self.T_sim = [i / self.T_sim[-1] for i in self.T_sim]
```

In the image the first derivative of the x-position w.r.t the timestamp is shown.

Ideally I would get a list showcasing the difference between both values for position at the scaled point in time.

Comment: You should add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question.

Comment: Which type of robot? Kuka ,ABB... ?
Please add some examples?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli thank you for your reply. I don't think it makes sense to add two lists of 300+ values.

Comment: @Danilo it is a pepper robot

Comment: @Chusikowski no, that's why I said *minimal*. You can add a snippet of code showing us how you deal with the problem in general, or even with a smaller list, what have you tried that did not work, etc. Anyway, if the problem is that you have lists of ~300 vs ~600 values you could take the small one and create the missing values with an average, or remove the excess values from the large one.

Comment: Am I reading the graph correctly , it is same time span for both graph? In other words odon simulator doesn't work for n seconds, and vcon frame for m? Also do you have access to the unit structure from which you can extract xpos and time - like a tuple or list ? Also one graph shows vectors, other dots. Is data for position determined by quaternions from linear jog or by coordinates?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli sometimes it isn't possible for robot work. Simulators often aren't well developed, so you often don't know with which kind of data you are working with.

Comment: You could resample and compare those values. One way is to have N=580+300=880 samples while eliminating duplicates, interpolating the values in between. Another way is to just pick a specific interval and use those values (N=500 for both for example). Is that feasible?

Comment: @Danilo you are correct. The times are different for the simulator and the robot. I just implemented in the question the way I scaled those two lists. I have acces to the whole data which is structured in lists. Both graphs show points, the "real robot" one just has a lot more outliers. Data for position is determined via Odometry.

Comment: @Caramiriel yes, thank you for your reply. I will try to do a dynamic window averaging to get an average of neighbouring values.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli you are right, I implemented the method I used for scaling the time lists. I will try what you proposed, thanks a lot.

Comment: Did Marco\s suggestion work ? @Chusikowski